# Reading Numbers From Text

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok so I have the following code:

```
string numbers = File.ReadAllText("numbers.txt");
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            List<string> List = new List<string>();
            List.AddRange(allNumbers);

            return List;
```

Currently the numbers.txt file is in a directory on my machine, but I want the text file to be integrated into my solution in a file such as numbers/numbers.txt. How do I read from *that* file instead of reading it from the default file VS2010 likes to read from? I already have a file in my solution called numbers with the respective file in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
string outputDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string fileName = Path.Combine(outputDirectory, "numbers.txt");
string numbers = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

Make sure you set the "Copy to output directory" property to "Copy if newer" for the file in question in your project.

Comment: It say's 'Assemly does not exsist in the current context' . I am missing a reference possibly? Also this is a web application not a standard console application. I am not sure if this matters.

Comment: Add `using System.Reflection` for console app. For web app yes it does matter - you have to pick a path on the file system base on Url - checkout `Server.MapPath`. I added the ASP.NET tag to your question

Comment: Yup, just got it. By resolving the issue like a normal person would haha

Comment: I am getting "Access to the path : C:/windows ect..." is denied. On the string numbers = File.ReadAllText(fileName); now. Any suggestions?

Comment: That can mean a few things. Make sure the file isn't already locked by another process. If one of your previous attempts at reading the file ended in an error, it may have put a lock on the file. Also, your process may simply not have the privileges to open that file.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the file as a resource to your project and use it easily later. Here is more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To usurp a little bit of BrokenGlass's code, you can also do this

```
string fileName = Server.MapPath("numbers/numbers.txt");
string numbers = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

[Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) converts a relative path on your site into a file path on the hosting machine.